# Android change rotation during Camera Intent image capture and not after

Tags: android, android-camera

I am opening the camera and take an image.
Here is my code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivity(takePictureIntent);

            }
        }
    }



    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath.add(image.getAbsolutePath()) ;
        return image;
    }

}
```

Now the issue is when opening the camera using intent the camera opens in landscape view on the emulator. Here is the image:

[The Camera view is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXeOO.jpg)
Now after I am taking an image here is how it looks like.

[After Image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz2Uq.png)

At this stage, there is no point rotate the image as the image is already cut off...
Ideas how to make sure the Android camera will save the image correctly...
btw... regardless of my app if I open the camera app on the emulator it does the same thing at the first the camera view covers the entire screen but when clicking on the button the image is cut off...

Answer (score 0):

> At this stage there is no point rotate the image as the image is already cut off

That's unlikely, but I cannot rule it out. Download the saved image to your development machine and check it there.

> Ideas how to make sure the android camera will save the image correctly

You don't. You delegated taking a photo to one of hundreds of possible camera apps. Each of those camera apps will do whatever its developers decided to have it do. None are bug-free. And there is no `EXTRA_PLEASE_DO_NOT_HAVE_BUGS` value that you can pass in `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

If you want more control, add photo-taking directly to your app, by using the camera APIs or a third-party library wrapper around those APIs.